# PHP $_POST empty after form submission

Tags: php, web-hosting

I have seen many other posts which supposedly contain the solution for this problem, but I could not solve it with them.

I'm creating a login page

```
<form action="https://www.tjoliveirafpereira.000webhostapp.com/code/CheckUser.php" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="six columns">
            <label for="NMEC">Nº Mecanográfico:</label>
            <input required class="u-full-width" type="text" id="NMEC">
            <label for="PIN">PIN:</label>
            <input required class="u-full-width" type="text" id="PIN">
        </div>            
    </div>        
    <input class="button-primary"  type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>
```

but when I print_r the $_POST variable, it shows that is empty (Array( ))..

```
print_r( $_POST);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: did you check for your input are having attribute `name` ?

Comment: Are you submitting the form?

Comment: Please post more of your source code. The complete form would be a start.

Comment: Try dump your input name with die
die(var_dump($_POST['your_input_name']));

Comment: Take a look at Uncle Joe's comment, you are missing the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the name attribute in your input fields. Try this:

```
<form action="https://www.tjoliveirafpereira.000webhostapp.com/code/CheckUser.php" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="six columns">
            <label for="NMEC">Nº Mecanográfico:</label>
            <input required class="u-full-width" name="myNMEC" type="text" id="NMEC">
            <label for="PIN">PIN:</label>
            <input required class="u-full-width" name="mypin" type="text" id="PIN">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="button-primary" name="mysubmit" type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>
```

Comment: @PHPWeb: As the question owner accepted this answer I suppose it solved the issue.

Comment: Yes it seems , but the problem the owner depicts seems something else .

Comment: @PHPWeb: I don't think so. Leaving out the name attribute of an input causes the mentioned problem of an empty $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned name attribute for text boxes having id="NMEC" and id="PIN", add name="NMEC" and name = "PIN" in the respective text boxes.This will solve the problem.